# Passing messages from iframe to parent window (cross-domain)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I need to pass a message from an iframe to the parent window. The parent window and iframe window are from different domains so I am running into difficulty with same origin restrictions (i.e., my attempts to access `window.parent` from the iframe are blocked).

I have been able to pass messages from the parent window to the iframe using the `window.location.hash` method as described in [this article](http://mattsnider.com/hash-hack-for-cross-domain-iframe-communication/). However, the method does not appear to work for sending messages from the iframe to the parent window.

I must also find a solution that works in IE7 and IE8.

Does anyone know how to do this?

I'm about to give up and build a web API to facilitate messages from the iframe to the parent window.

Answer (score 0):

Take closer look at `window.postMessage` API. It allows you to send message across all domains and between iframes. Perfectly works on IE as well

Comment: I didn't have luck with this earlier -- doesn't appear to be supported by IE7: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage